# I am not able to understand this svg path code

Tags: html, css, svg

I can't understand this SVG path code. Normally SVG path code is not like this. This code draws letters "The Verge". I want to draw some other stuff by doing the same method. By I can't understand the code, I tried many different things but could not draw the letters, I want to draw by applying the same code method as mentioned below.

Below is the code

```html
<svg fill="#fff" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 291.4 1280 217.2">

    <path d="M0 292.1v58.1h39.7v153.2h67.1V292.1M220.1 
    372.4h-31.4v-22.3h15.8v-58h-82.8v211.3h67v-79.9h31.4v79.9h67.2V292.1h-67.2M302 503.4h124.3v-58.2h-60.2v-24.6h38.3v-48.2h-38.3v-22.2h60.2v-58.1H302M954.8 363.6c0-45.6-33.7-71.5-81.5-71.5h-74.7v211.2h67.1v-54.1l38.4 54.1h75.7l-54.4-81c19.6-10.7 29.4-30.2 29.4-58.7M865.5 387v-39.3c9.3 0 20.7 2.8 24.1 13 .3.9.5 1.9.8 2.9 0 .1 0 .3.1.4.1 1 .3 2.2.3 3.4 0 15.7-14.3 19.6-25.3 19.6M559.2 420.8h-.6l-4.8-17.4-15-53.1h26.4l17.4-58.2h-134l76.8 211.2h68.8l8.3-22.6s36.8-99.8 56.9-154.2v176.8h124.3v-58.2h-60.2v-24.6h38.2v-48.1h-38.2v-22.2h60.2V292H598l-38.8 128.8zM1280 350.3v-58.1h-124.3v211.2H1280v-58.2h-60.3v-24.6h38.3v-48h-38.3v-22.3">
    </path>
    
    <path d="M1142.8 459.1V373H1048v48h35.3v17.1c-2.7 2.4-8.5 3.7-14.5 3.7-24.6 0-42.8-19.4-42.8-43.1s17.7-44.7 42.3-44.7c14.9 0 50.2.1 50.2.1v-62.6h-16.1c-30 0-59.9-2.4-87.4 11.8-21.7 11.2-38.9 30.2-48 52.8-5.3 13.3-8 27.7-8 42 0 59.9 47 110.4 107.9 110.4 30.2 0 59.7-11.3 75.8-25.4.1-14.6.1-16.8.1-24">
    </path>
  
    <path d="M0 292.1v58.1h39.7v153.2h67.1V292.1M220.1
   372.4h-31.4v-22.3h15.8v-58h-82.8v211.3h67v-79.9h31.4v79.9h67.2V292.1h-67.2M302 503.4h124.3v-58.2h-60.2v-24.6h38.3v-48.2h-38.3v-22.2h60.2v-58.1H302M954.8">
    </path>
    
</svg>
```

Comment: [This explains the syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathElement). If you just want to draw something though, use an editor such as Inkscape.

Comment: This is completely normal SVG path code. M is absolute move, v is relative vertical line, V is absolute vertical line,  h is relative horizontal line, c is cubic bezier, z is close path, l is relative line etc.

Comment: @MichaelMullany Yeah thanks, I wasn't able to understand because this code was a bit complex. That's why I was confused. But now I got it